# Converting Long to Date gives one day less

Tags: java

Im converting long value into Date using `new Date(long)` for the same value my local machine gives

> Long Value:- 1481394600000
>
> Date:- 2016-12-11 (Actual value)
>
> Date:- 2016-12-10 (I get this)

However, I get proper value in my local setup. But Remote machine gives one day less. Both the machines are in UTC time zone.

Comment: I get the same value as you (10/12). Can you post your code? Also are you using java.util.Date?

Comment: Please search Stack Overflow before posting. This has been covered many times already. Tip: search for java.time milliseconds epoch Instant ZonedDateTime

Answer (score 1):

On my local computer to run:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.Month;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.of(2016, Month.DECEMBER, 11, 12, 30);
        ZonedDateTime zdt = dateTime.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);

        String dataInUTC = zdt.toString();
        System.out.println(dataInUTC);
    }
}
```

Result:

```
2016-12-11T12:30Z
```

Maybe you should use the LocalDateTime and ZoneDateTime

Comment: FYI, this answer uses troublesome confusing old date-time classes, now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.